# How do I prevent RewriteRule from ignoring this URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this RewriteRule :

`RewriteRule !^(div|sitemapXML|cache|AJAX|xml|html|favicon.ico|robots.txt|script|cms|style|image|inc|img|templates|index.html) index.php`

But for example "http://www.mydomain.com/divindu/" gets ignored because of the excluded "div". What is the best way to go about folders in here? Should I put a forward slash after the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type, regular file or directory, you can append a slash `/` or an end of string dollar sign `$`. You can also move the pattern to a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and split directories and files into two

```
# exclude some directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(div|sitemapXML|cache|AJAX|xml|html|script|cms|style|image|inc|img|templates)/
# exclude some existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon.ico|robots.txt|index.html)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Or, if you want to exclude all existing files and directories as @Niels assumed, you can just use

```
# exclude existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# exclude directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to achieve a catch-all rule that ignores existing files. You should simply use Apache's FallbackResource directive for that. For older versions of Apache, or more granlar control, look into the special -d and -f flags to RewriteCond, you can use them to explicitly exclude existing files and folders from a RewriteRule.